# VirtualKeyboard API - hide() method not working

Tags: javascript, android, android-softkeyboard, virtual-keyboard, android-virtual-keyboard

I have a JavaScript application which also runs on mobile devices (Android, Chrome Browser).
The requirement is a input field which has inital focus without showing the Softkeyboard. This will be used as a scan field. Only when the user manually type/touch into the field the keyboard should appear.

I'am using this code:

```
if ('virtualKeyboard' in navigator) {

    const myInput = getElementById("myinput");

    myInput.setAttribute("virtualkeyboardpolicy", "manual");

    navigator.virtualKeyboard.overlaysContent = true;

    myInput.addEventListener("pointerup", () => {
        navigator.virtualKeyboard.show();
    });

    myInput.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
        navigator.virtualKeyboard.hide();
    });

}
```

It works quite properly except hiding the keyboard within the "focusout" event. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I whould expect that the Softkeyboard will be closed after calling the hide() method but this isn't the case. I'am not sure if this depends on the events (Pointerevents, Focusevents).

Comment: I see the focusout event listener, but am wondering what would make it fire if myInput has initial focus.

Comment: The pointerup event will not be fired on inital focus. Only if the user tipps into the field. Both events are firing correctly. It seems to be that the hide() method is ignored in the focusout event. But I don't know why...

Comment: So, even when the focusout event fires, the soft keyboard remains visible?

Comment: Yes it remains visible. It depends on the manual mode (virtualkeyboardpolicy).

Comment: Not exactly sure what is happening, but from your description, it sounds like myInput is regaining focus immediately after losing it which would almost certainly cause the keyboard to be shown again. Have you tried creating a focusin handler with some logging to determine if that is happening?>

Comment: @benny I have the exact same issue. See my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77795626/virtual-keyboard-api-hide-isnt-working with the attached codesandbox.

Comment: @AviKaminetzky I believe that depends on the Android device.

Comment: @benny Is there any discussion _anywhere_ about that? I'm having trouble finding any discussions.