# Virtual Keyboard API hide() isn't working

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

For a webpage running on Android Chrome, I'm attempting to implement the [VirtualKeyboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VirtualKeyboard/hide) on an input field:

```html
      <input
        id="my-input"
        placeholder="Click to edit"
        inputmode="text"
        virtualkeyboardpolicy="manual"
      />
```

The Javascript/jQuery part

```js
      $("#my-input").on("focus", () => {
        navigator.virtualKeyboard.show();
      });

      $("#my-input").on("blur", () => {
        navigator.virtualKeyboard.hide();
      });
```

The `show()` method works fine, but the `hide()` methods doesn't work at all. Why is the `hide()` method being ignored?

Live demo with [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/virtual-keyboard-api-forked-gm7c9d?file=%2Findex.html%3A37%2C12)

Comment: There's a ticket tracking this in Chromium's bug tracker: [#1444929](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1444929). Unfortunately, it's still not resolved at the time of writing. The reporter has proposed a workaround in [comment 3](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1444929#c3).

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VirtualKeyboard/hide

> This method only works if the currently-focused element's virtualKeyboardPolicy attribute is set to manual and inputmode isn't set to none.

`blur` is called only after losing the focus while `hide` works only if the input is focused.

```js
$("#my-input").on("blur", () => {
  $("#my-input").is(":focus"); // FALSE!
  navigator.virtualKeyboard.hide();
});
```

You need to find another event (ideally before `blur` or `focusout`) and try to close the keyboard from there while the input still has focus.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score -1):

You need to opt-in for the API to work.
Make sure to add this code before calling the API:

```
navigator.virtualKeyboard.overlaysContent = true;
```

This needs to be double checked, but make sure that you're using the API in the top frame, it seems like some browser might not give access when it's in an iframe.

Comment: That only controls how the viewport is resized, not the functionality. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VirtualKeyboard_API#opt_out_of_the_automatic_virtual_keyboard_behavior

Comment: Give it a try. "To opt out of the automatic virtual keyboard behavior of the browser, use navigator.virtualKeyboard.overlaysContent = true."

On Chrome's website it says:
"To tell the browser that you are taking care of virtual keyboard occlusions yourself, you need to first opt in to the new virtual keyboard behavior by setting the boolean property overlaysContent to true."
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/virtual-keyboard#opting_in_to_the_new_virtual_keyboard_behavior

Comment: I tested it and it didn't make a difference.